# Is there a way to login on behalf of User in Microsoft Identity without going through login page?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, microsoft-identity-platform

We have implemented Azure Identity in our web application for user authentication and we have a sign in page setup in azure where user can sign in. I know there is option in Microsoft Identity Platform for "on behalf of(OBO)" login after user logged in once but what I need is to log in user when user have never been logged in previously. I need this for demo purpose. A demo user which we can log in directly to our application without going through the login page.

Comment: The combination of your question along with the tags added to it make your use case and desired flow unclear. Could you add some detail, please?

Comment: A default user is a GUEST Account.  So you can allow GUEST Access for the role.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole made some changes.

Comment: Please check this it may help to you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#supported-app-scenarios-and-additional-resources

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) supports several authentication flows for use in different application scenario and one of them is [On-behalf-of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#on-behalf-of).

It states about an application invokes a service or web API, which in turn needs to call another service or web API. The idea is to propagate the delegated user identity and permissions through the request chain.

Through this Authentication flow you can propagate the user’s identity in the WebAPI without user engagement and can login on behalf of user.

> The [OAuth 2 on-behalf-of authentication
> flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)
> flow is used when an application invokes a service or web API that in
> turn needs to call another service or web API. The idea is to
> propagate the delegated user identity and permissions through the
> request chain. For the middle-tier service to make authenticated
> requests to the downstream service, it needs to secure an access token
> from the Microsoft identity platform *on behalf of* the user.
>
> [image]
>
> In the preceding diagram:
>
> 1. The application acquires an access token for the web API.
> 2. A client (web, desktop, mobile, or single-page application) calls a protected web API, adding the access token as a bearer token in the
>    authentication header of the HTTP request. The web API authenticates
>    the user.
> 3. When the client calls the web API, the web API requests another token on-behalf-of the user.
> 4. The protected web API uses this token to call a downstream web API on-behalf-of the user. The web API can also later request tokens for
>    other downstream APIs (but still on behalf of the same user).

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#on-behalf-of

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROPC (resource owner password credential) grant for a non-interactive sign in.  Your application will directly pass the username and password of the user to sign in.  It won't work for all scenarios though (for example, if multi-factor authentication is turned on).  [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) or [view a sample app](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2) that uses ROPC.